# postgresql: table create partition by 'user_id', and can i known record in which sub-partition by given a 'user_id'?

Tags: postgresql

The table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."vi_history" (
  "history_id" varchar(255) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" NOT NULL,
  "user_id" varchar(255) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  "updated" timestamptz(6) DEFAULT now(),
  "created" timestamptz(6) DEFAULT now()
) PARTITION BY HASH("user_id");
```

I want to know when get a user_id = 'USER001', where the sub_table it will store,  `visit_history_1` or `visit_history_33` or some sub-table?

Is there some way to do it, thanks

Comment: That partition definition is invalid. You need to provide a partitioning strategy, e.g. `partition by list` or `partition by hash`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for reminding, and the table `PARTITION BY HASH`

Comment: no way, the ```BY HASH``` uses some internal hashing algorithm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61409008/test-hash-function-for-postgres-table-partitioning